# Where can I ask to help me to look for resourses like books, scientific articles and so on?

Tags: discussion

Where can I ask to help me to look for resourses like books, scientific articles and so on?

For example, if I want resourses on a specific topic (Does oxygen induce coagulation?), what tag I have to use? Maybe literature-search and literatue?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 5):

If you want resources on a specific research area, that is considered off-topic on Academia.SE, since the site is devoted to questions about academic *practice*, not the specific content of research. You might be able to ask such a question on a content-specific SE site, but most likely such questions will be poorly received.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I think your best bet is **your local university librarian**. Helping people find relevant literature is part of their job description.